# Comparing two fields with IN clausule

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I compare two fields from two tables with IN clausule, but, one of the fields has one one "value" and the other field I have a group of values?

```
TABLE_FOO:
FOO (int)
1
2

TABLE_BAR:
BAR     FOO (string)
1       1,2
```

Thats my SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_FOO, TABLE_BAR WHERE TABLE_FOO.FOO IN TABLE_BAR.FOO
```

I can't get the result of this query.

EDIT
I think that its not a duplicated question, as my problem here is to "Link" two tables through relational (joins) 'select'.

Comment: The real solution is to change your table design. Never store multiple values in  a single column!

Comment: Its not "my" table design. If it was, I never would do that. Unfortunable, that is how "they" are doing it. Sorry

Comment: @Killer - the JOIN condition is similar to a WHERE condition. The incorrect answer posted by Jon Ekiz is just his misunderstanding of the correct one, from the linked question. Read the answer there and you will be able to fix your JOIN.

Comment: I will try @mathguy